# Deveria o sistema impossibilitar a marcação de repostas como certas durante algum tempo?

Tags: debate, suporte, respostas

Tenho notado que quando surgem perguntas que demandam respostas mais técnicas e teóricas, e na primeira resposta de dignatários do site, pessoas com muito status, rapidamente essas respostas são escolhidas como "a correta".

Não desmerecendo o valor de tais pessoas, pelo contrário, com elas se aprende muito, mas, será que o sistema não deveria ter um tempo mínimo para o AP marcar a resposta como certa? Talvez, quem sabe, de 1 hora? Isso porque em muitos casos nem dá tempo de elaborar uma resposta, talvez até melhor do que a foi escolhida, mas o AP já selecionou a outra resposta como certa e parece que o esforço foi em vão. Sei que nem sempre a escolhida é a melhor, mas o fato é que a outra foi escolhida, e dificilmente o AP irá mudar isso.

Será que o SOpt não deveria ver isso, definir um tempo mínimo (se já existe, eu não sei) para que o AP marque a resposta como escolhida?

Comment: DvD se o AP quiser ele pode alterar a resposta marcada como certa. Eu já fiz isso numa pergunta no SOen, passado 2 anos surgiu uma nova resposta que era muito melhor que a que estava marcada, e eu mudei para a nova e agora está até com melhor votação.

Comment: Há tempo minimo sim, é de [15 minutos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099/310559). Agora o fato de um "usuario veterano" ter respondido nunca deveria ser empecilho pra nenhum outro usuário responder, não se apegue ao "accept", se você tem algum conhecimento para complementar, tua resposta será tão bem avaliada pela comunidade quanto a do outro usuário. O fato dela não ser aceita não significa que não seja boa e nem que não sirva para o OP, alias, já vi muitos casos em que a aceita sequer era uma boa resposta, e tendo outras melhores e mais bem votadas e que respondem a duvida muito melhor.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente acho que apenas a votação a longo prazo tem mais significado que o fato de ser aceite. A votação será um juizo de valor da comunidade inteira e o certo é um juizo de valor do AP, e o AP nem sempre tem os conhecimentos necessários para avaliar de forma correta as respostas

Comment: Tem um outro lado a considerar: tem gente que lê a resposta e não volta mais. Se impedir a aceitação, a postagem fica sem aceitação "pro resto da vida" (se bem que tem casos em que era melhor que tivesse ficado sem mesmo). Ainda é bom quando é de usuários bem pontuados, afinal muitos deles em geral são mais frequentes no site e corrigem e melhoram seus posts depois, com o tempo e sugestões de colegas. O pior é quando a pessoa aceita o primeiro post "jogado de qualquer jeito" no site e some, e o "aceitado" se satisfaz com a resposta como está.

Comment: A verdadeira "correçao" no site seria a aceita não ficar presa no topo, e a ordenação ser sempre por votos. Bastaria um linkzinho embaixo da pergunta "Ver resposta escolhida", no caso da aceita não ser a mais votada, com uma simples ancora.

Comment: @Bacco essa ideia de ter no topo a mais votada é interessante. Talvez com uma variante: o algoritmo usar a mais votada nos últimos dias/meses. Isto porque a mais votada pode ter 5 anos e haver hoje maneiras novas e melhores de fazer isso.

Comment: A proposta do @Bacco de ordernar por votos e colocar um link para a pergunta escolhida faz muito sentido com o princípio de que a resposta aceita é apenas mais uma e não significa que é melhor do que as outras. Enfim, essa mudança tira o foco da resposta escolhida tratando-a como outra qualquer. Eu acho a mudança coerente com a proposta do site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deve-se lembrar que a resposta marcada como "aceita" **não é a melhor resposta**. Ela é apenas **uma resposta que ajudou** o AP no seu problema.
O AP não tem a responsabilidade de marcar a melhor resposta.

Eu custei pra entender isso quando utilizava só o SOen e continuo vendo que muitos usuários não compreendem isso.

Existe realmente o fenômeno de "[arma mais rápida do oeste](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/155051)" em toda a rede. E é considerado por muitos um problema.

Mas limitar **demais** o tempo de resposta não vai ajudar. Pode na verdade desencorajar as pessoas de acompanhar as perguntas mais novas já que não vão poder respondê-las.

Answer (score 8):

Eu acompanho o site desde que foi criado. Geralmente as pessoas tem muitos pontos porque suas respostas são bem consideradas, e não o contrário.

Pegue algumas perguntas nas quais tenha percebido o que descrevestes aqui e faça uma análise da qualidade das respostas (seria interessante adicionar links a elas). Você logo perceberá, na maioria dos casos:

- Além da resposta marcada como correta, há outras boas respostas bastante votadas;
- Em geral, as respostas com mais votos são completas e explicam a solução dada;
- As respostas com menos votos são mais curtas, ou não respondem completamente ao problema.

Outra coisa: todas as pessoas que tem muitos pontos hoje começaram com no máximo 101 pontos. Elas não teriam chegado à pontuação que tem atualmente caso se sentissem intimidadas pela presença de boas respostas de outras pessoas.

E finalmente: a única restrição que existe e que deve ser de fato impeditiva para a participação de novatos é nas [perguntas protegidas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Os usuários com quinze mil pontos ou mais podem proteger uma pergunta para impedir a participação de usuários novos nela, mas isso somente é feito em casos especiais e afeta praticamente apenas usuários realmente novos.